# Limitar as casas decimais Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Fiz um script em python e preciso de ajuda.

Como podem ver, uma planilha em excel é aberta, trata os dados e retorna para outra planilha.

Ao abrir a planilha nova, os números ficam enormes e a data também, por  exemplo, 1.333333 e eu gostaria que ficasse 1.33.

```
    put = pd.read_excel('Operacao_inicial.xlsm', sheet_name='Rastreador_PUT', decimal=",", thousands='.', inex_col=(), false_values='NaN', keep_default_na=False, header=8)
    
    put =pd.DataFrame(put, columns=['STRIKE','ATIVO','VENC.','Robo PUT','Real Time','TIR (%)','Strike VS Cot. (%)','Money','Negocios'])

    put['STRIKE'] = pd.to_numeric(put['STRIKE'], errors='coerce')
    put['VENC.'] = pd.to_datetime(put['VENC.'], errors='coerce')
    put['Real Time'] = pd.to_numeric(put['Real Time'], errors='coerce')
    put['TIR (%)'] = pd.to_numeric(put['TIR (%)']*100, errors='coerce')
    put['Strike VS Cot. (%)'] = pd.to_numeric(put['Strike VS Cot. (%)']*100, errors='coerce')
    put['Money'] = pd.to_numeric(put['Money'], errors='coerce')
    put['Negocios'] = pd.to_numeric(put['Negocios'], errors='coerce')

    put.to_excel('Robo_operacional.xlsx', index=0)

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(coletar_dados)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para arredondar as casas decimais é algo bem simples... Basta usar o round! Olha como é simples:

```
round(1232.21, 2) #o primeiro argumento é o numero a ser arredondado e o segundo são as casa decimais
```

Você pode colocar uma variável como argumento também, como por exemplo:

```
num =  123.32
print(round(num, 2)
```

Espero ter ajudado!